# iOS: How to stream (live sending) data over HTTP?

Tags: ios, http, streaming

I know, this topic's title is pretty general and I thought this problem was easy to solve (I made it on Android very easily). But on iOS... Well, this question exists so....

I have a device and I want to stream data (audio data to be precise) on it. The protocol I have to use is HTTP. Actually, I have to build ans send a single HTTP request containing some data in its body, then, as and when my "producer" (here, a process that resample/encode audio data) gives new data to transmit, send it through this request body. It sounds weird for HTTP, but it's like HTTP multipart without boundary (data are just sent one behind the others).

For example, in Java I initialize a `HttpUrlConnection` with URL and headers, I precise the `Content-Length` header to "9999999" (as it is wrote in the targeted device's documentation) with `/*my connection*/.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(9999999);`. I don't call `connect()`method but I get the output stream (`getOutputStream()`) and when my producer gives new data, I just call `/*my output stream*/.write(/*my data*/);` then `/*my output stream*/.flush();`

So, I tried with `NSURLSession` and with low-level APIs `NSInputStream`and `NSOutputStream`. But in each case, I can't achieve that:

- With `NSURLSession` I called `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:` but the callback `needNewBodyStream:` is only called once (or twice in case of new auth). So I only send one data packet in the input stream.
- With `NSInputStream`and `NSOutputStream` connection is close by targeted device without error before I can send any data with standard TCP ending on input stream (except HTTP headers).

I think this is something a lot of people did and they is a way I didn't see, no? Please help me by give me examples (this'll be perfect) or avises about what API I have to choose or a specific parameter to apply?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

My problem is similar to **[this](http://www.duanqu.tech/questions/1165869/ios-http-multipart-form-streaming-request)** but it's an other (shorter) way to explain it.

**EDIT 2**

Here is my code when I use NSURLSession (I prefer keep using that if possible):

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration* defaultConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSOperationQueue* operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:operationQueue];

NSInputStream* inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:/*data*/];

NSURL* url = /*init from string*/
NSMutableRequest* request : [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBodyStream = inputStream;
/*Add some headers to request*/

NSURLSessionUploadTask* uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request];
[uploadTask resume];
```

To be precise, I didn't put auth information in URL. Delegates's methods are called in this order : `didSendBodyData` -> `didReceiveChallenge` (this is where I perform authentication and it works because I received just before a 401 and nothing after) -> `needNewBodyStream` (this is where I put my data in the input stream for the completion handler) -> `didSendBodyData` -> `didFinishCollectingMetrics` -> `didCompleteWithError` (with code -1005 : kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork). Strange thing is that data is transmited well (the first data packet) because I can heard sound in the target device for some instants.

To be more precise again, here is the network traffic during connection:

- Send **TCP** SYN, ECN, CWR
- Rcv **TCP** SYN, ACK, ECN
- Send **TCP** ACK
- Send **TCP** segment of reassembled PDU (my HTTP request and data *without* auth) (x7, each followed by an ACK response)
- Rcv **HTTP** 401 (because required digest)
- ... **TCP** Succession of ACK, FIN/ACK, SYN/ECN/CWR...
- Send **TCP** segment of reassembled PDU (my HTTP request and data *with* auth) (x7, each followed by an ACK response)

And then (I don't know why):

- Rcv **TCP** END, ACK
- Send **TCP** ACK
- Send **TCP** END, ACK
- Rcv **TCP** ACK

Comment: Are you using the shared URLSession or have you created a new default or background session? In the second case try to set `sessionConfig.isDiscretionary = false` and `sessionConfig.networkServiceType` properties

Comment: @Roran Thanks for your comment, I edited my question with a few code showing my NSURLSession usage. I tried what you said but there is no difference in behavior.

Comment: you can try to read this: [link](http://www.beardedhacker.com/blog/2016/08/31/streamed-upload-example-with-swift-and-node-dot-js/)

Comment: @Roran Thanks, I read it but it is for a "one shot " data upload, my problem is to upload data in continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, I've got the answer and I think it's a good idea to share it. Actually it's very easy: the trick was just not explicit at all. The callback `needNewBodyStream:` is called once (or more, see doc) and we just have to bind the `NSInputStream` object with a `NSOutputStream` one. Then, data is wrote in the `NSOutputStream`'s callback as and when the "producer" gives new data. Previously, my connection was closed because after the `needNewBodyStream` call there was nothing to send.

Part of the `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` implementation:

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
    needNewBodyStream:(void (^)(NSInputStream * bodyStream))completionHandler
{
    NSInputStream* inputStream = nil;
    NSOutputStream* outputStream = nil;

    // Bind inputStream and outputStream

    self.inputStream = inputStream;
    self.outputStream = outputStream;
    [self.outputStream setDelegate:/*NSStreamDelegate implementation*/];
    [self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.outputStream open];

    completionHandler(self.inputStream);
}
```

Part of the `NSStreamDelegate` implementation:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            // to handle...
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            // Producer/Consumer's consumer here, and when data is available:
            [self.outputStream write:/*data*/ maxLength:/*data length*/];                
            break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            // to handle...
            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            // to handle...
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Now you can stream "in live" over HTTP, enjoy :)